# Auto.Arima transform timeseries and xreg correlation with lagged forecast timeseries

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast an `auto.arima()` model like the one below.

I was wondering in general if it was necessary to transform a timeseries so that it resembled a normal distribution before passing it to `auto.arima()`?

Also does it matter if your `xreg=...` predictor is correlated with a lag of the timeseries you're trying to predict, or vice versa?

Code:

```
tsTrain <-tsTiTo[1:60]
tsTest <- tsTiTo[61:100]


Xreg<-CustCount[1:100]

##Predictor
xregTrain2 <- Xreg[1:60]
xregTest2 <- Xreg[61:100]


Arima.fit2 <- auto.arima(tsTrain, xreg = xregTrain2)

Acast2<-forecast(Arima.fit2, h=40, xreg = xregTest2)
```

Data:

```
#dput(ds$CustCount[1:100])

CustCount = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 6, 8, 5, 2, 7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 8, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, NA, NA, 4, 2, 2, 4, 11, 2, 8, 1, 4, 7, 11, 5, 3, 10, 7, 1, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5, 9, 6, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3, 1 )

# dput(tsTiTo[1:100])
tsTiTo = c(45, 34, 11, 79, 102, 45, 21, 45, 104, 20, 2, 207, 45, 2, 3, 153, 8, 2, 173, 11, 207, 79, 45, 153, 192, 173, 130, 4, 173, 174, 173, 130, 79, 154, 4, 104, 192, 153, 192, 104, 28, 173, 52, 45, 11, 29, 22, 81, 7, 79, 193, 104, 1, 1, 46, 130, 45, 154, 153, 7, 174, 21, 193, 45, 79, 173, 45, 153, 45, 173, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 79, 45, 79, 173, 45, 2, 173, 130, 104, 19, 4, 34, 2, 192, 42, 41, 31, 39, 11, 79, 4, 79)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no and no to both questions. See the long answer below.

> I was wondering in general if it was necessary to transform a
> timeseries so that it resembled a normal distribution before passing
> it to auto.arima()?

No. In the case of time series data, it is the innovation errors that you want to be normally distributed. Not the time series you are modelling.

This is similar to in the case of liner regression model, you don't expect the predictors to be normally distributed. It is the errors that you'd expect to be normally distributed.

> Also does it matter if your xreg=... predictor is correlated with a
> lag of the timeseries you're trying to predict, or vice versa?

You'd hope xreg are correlated this way. We are typing to use that information when looking for an appropriate model to forecast.